# S3 Access for only Cognito Authenticated User

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

For a small project i am developing using angular framework, i have autenticated users with access, id and refresh tokens from cognito which is used to log into the site. Now is there any way to use these tokes to grant access to uploading and downloading files from and to my s3 bucket?

Comment: You can do this with federated identities, or you can just create a signed url.

Comment: can you provide me any resources that points towards how to create signed url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pre-signed URL for the get or put operation, and pass that back to the frontend which will do the actual upload or download using that url.

Here's an example from the golang docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html

Comment: generation of presigned url should be done on the server side ?

Comment: Yes, @joel it should be done by the server.